# Restore data from lost partition after raid synchronization

Tags: linux, centos

I have Centos Linux server hosted online, with 2 hard drives.
By mistake I integrated raid array over the hard drive I have data on it, and I stopped synchronize on 20% of synchronization.
Is it possible to restore the lost data on hard drive from rescue mode ? and what are tools could help on that ?

Disk /dev/sda: 3000 GB (=> 2794 GiB)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3000 GB (=> 2794 GiB)
Total capacity 5589 GiB with 2 Disks

My active hard drive was /dev/sdb and after raid configuration /dev/sda overwrite /dev/sdb

Personalities : [raid1]
md3 : active raid1 sdb5[1]
      1847605568 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1]
      1073741632 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1]
      524224 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1]
      8388544 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

When I discovered the mistake I stopped the process and mark it as failed so I lost md0 and md1 and md2, the process stopped at 20% of md2 synchronize

I can access the hard drives from rescue mode and able to use testdisk

Answer (score 2):

If `sda` really overwrited `sdb`, you are out of luck: not only the partition table, but also key filesytem structures *and most actual data* where destroyed.

You can only try to use `testdisk` (also know as `photorec`) to recover what remains from your data; however, 100% data recovery is basically impossible.

The best advise is to restrore from your backup...

Comment: `testdisk` attempts to recover partitions; `photorec` attempts to recover files. They are two separate but closely related utilities.